# Symfony Form to store a selection of User Interests to UserInterests

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

My aim is to use a Symfony Form to allow a user to choose multiple interests and save these relationally against their user.

I have three entities to map and store this data:

```
User
 - id
 - name

Interest
 - id
 - name

UserInterest
 - id
 - user_id (FK ManyToOne user.id)
 - interest_id (FK ManyToOne interest.id)
```

I'm struggling to find the most dynamic *Symfony* way to process and save the `Interest`s of a `User` to the `UserInterest` entity.

***InterestsController.php***

```
public function interests(Request $request)
{
    $error = null;

    $userInterests = new UserInterest();
    $userInterests->setUser($this->getUser());

    $form = $this->createForm(UserAccountInterests::class, $userInterests);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        try {
            $this->entityManager->persist($userInterests);
            $this->entityManager->flush();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    $parameters = [
        'error' => $error,
        'user_interests_form' => $form->createView()
    ];

    return $this->render('user/interests.html.twig', $parameters);
}
```

***UserInterestsType.php***

```
class UserInterestsType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    $builder
        ->add('interest', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Interest::class,
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true
        ])
        ->add('update', SubmitType::class);
    }
 }
```

## The problem

The issue I'm facing at the moment is that upon form submission this creates an instantiation of the `UserInterest` entity linked to a `user` but with multiple selected `Interest` as an array and not multiple `UserInterest`.

How can I do this in the proper Symfony way to allow for one form and simple controller logic so the user can load the page, select their interests from a multiple checkbox type, click save and then when the form is reloaded they are auto populated as prior selection?

Comment: In your case you need a `CollectionType` not `EntityType`. Collection type `entry_type` should be InterestType. Check CollectionType documentation

Comment: This is what you want: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first solution is a bit too complicated for what you're trying to achieve. If you just want user to select some interests, You don't need a UserInterest entity.

The only use i can think of for a new entity dedicated to that relation is if the relation comes with some extra properties you want to persist, like the date the relation start, maybe an order or a priority or anything you need. If the only data you're gonna store are userId and interestId, then a new entity will not bring you much but complexity. 
You don't need a CollectionType either(you don't create new interest on this form anyway). Go with a simple ManyToMany relation between User and Interest

```
 User:
  type: entity
  manyToMany:
    interests:
      targetEntity: Interest
      inversedBy: users
      joinTable: 
        ## name will be the name of the table storing your entities 's relations
        ## Beware not to give it a name already defined for an entity table (like your UserInterest wich you don't need anymore)
        name: users_interests 
        joinColumns:
          user_id:
            referencedColumnName: id
        inverseJoinColumns:
          interest_id:
            referencedColumnName: id

Interest:
  type: entity
  manyToMany:
    users:
      targetEntity: User
      mappedBy: interests
```

Then you can use a simple multiple EntityType in a form where data_class is User and class of your entitytype is Interest:

```
class UserInterestsType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    $builder
        ->add('interests', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Interest::class,
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => true,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->orderBy('u.name', 'ASC');
}, 
        ])
        ->add('update', SubmitType::class);
    }
 }
```

Then let's say you want to retrieve Users sharing a specific interest or the Interests of a specific User, you will have these kind of queries in your existing User and Interest Repositories:

```
// UserRepository: All users sharing one (or more) interests
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$repository = $em->getRepository('YourNamespace:User');
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('u')
    ->innerJoin('u.interests', 'i')
    ->where('i.id = :interest_id')
    ->setParameter('interest_id', 5) // just for the example
    ->getQuery()->getResult();

// InterestRepository: All interests of one user 
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$repository = $em->getRepository('YourNamespaceYourBundle:Interest');
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('i')
    ->innerJoin('i.users', 'u')
    ->where('u.id = :user_id')
    ->setParameter('user_id', 1)
    ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: This is close but I get: `The table with name 'table.user_interest' already exists.`

Comment: Okay did you delete your entity UserInterest ? or get sure that the entity UserInterest you created before won't end up creating a user_interest table ?

Comment: But I have a `user_interesest` table, that is where the relations are stored? Which interests each user has related to them.

Comment: Yes but this table is now generated by the ManyToMany relation, you can specify the name in your YAML file via joinTable->name parameter ( i edited my response) . Problem is, if you keep your UserInterest entity, she'll probably generate a user_interest(s) table of his own

Comment: Perfect, this works! If I want to query the new table that was generated, should I use custom queries instead of an entity manager?

Comment: You don't have have to use custom queries. New table is just here to store relations not "objects" . Therefore you will fetch your User/Interest relations from User or Interest repositories depending on you needing Interest for a specific user or Users who share a specific Interest. I edit the response